# Return value is not the same as predicted from a defined function

Tags: python-3.7

```
james=open('C:/Users/skora da_bura/Documents/data.txt')
jake=james.read()
james.close()

numblist=[]
charlist=[]

def Read(numblist,charlist):
   for i in range(0,len(jake),4):

      numblist.append(int(jake[i]))

   for i in range(2,len(jake),4):
      charlist.append(jake[i])
      Bring = numblist,charlist

   james = open('C:/Users/skora da_bura/Documents/data.txt')
   jake22 = james.readlines()
   james.close()
   back='Number of lines read',len(jake22)

   return back

    print(Read([],[]))
    print(charlist)
```

the `charlist` returns [] even though I had appended values to it to make a list when I was defining the function Read.
I don't seem to see what the problem is with the code

Answer (score 0):

The `charlist` you define in the signature of `Read` shadows the global `charlist`. They're different variables that happen to have the same name. If you intend to modify the global variable, you shouldn't try to pass it as a parameter.